# Communicating from node to python using json gives me error

Tags: python, node.js

I'm trying to communicate to python from node using PythonShell. When I set the mode to json, I get an error

```
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token W in JSON at position 0
```

My python file so far contains the following

```
import json
import random
import tensorflow
import tflearn
import numpy
import sys
import pickle
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()
nltk.download('punkt')
```

This is how I'm calling the python file from node:

```
const options = {
    mode: 'json',
    pythonOptions: ['-u'],
    pythonPath: 'python'
};
let pyshell = new PythonShell('./python/script.py', options);

pyshell.on('message', async function(message) {
    autoResponseHandler(message);
});
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I set the mode to json correctly?

Comment: Is that all the code for ./python/script.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

In your python script, you need to return a message of the json-form '{ ex: "something"}'.

---

I suspect you're attempting to pass a plain string as the message to pyshell.on().  Before you pass 'message', you need to convert it to JSON format.

So when I run the following code:

```
import json
import random
import tensorflow
import tflearn
import numpy
import sys
import pickle
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()
message = nltk.download('punkt')
print(message)
```

The output is 'true'...  What is your intention here?

Comment: I have a full python file, but I'm trying to get to the source of the problem, so I commented everything else out, but the imports, and I get the error message

Comment: @Jessica the problem is that you've set the mode to json, but you're not sending a response message that is json.  Try changing the mode to 'text' and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: When I change it to text works. I didn't send any message. But it's possible that the depreciation/error get sent over, and that is what messing with it. Is there a way to silent the messages?  I tried: import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
, but it's still giving me error messages

Comment: I don't know of anyway to silence depreciation warnings or errors.  I usually just address/fix them because it's bad-practice to let them persist.  However, here is a link to various fixes for the tensor flow warnings. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27023